# Finding largest and smallest normalized value based on IEEE floating point

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Based on IEEE floating point rep, I want to find the largest and smallest normalized value that can be obtained using one signed bit, 4 exp bits and 3 frac bits?

How do I find this out?

Answer (score 0):

Largest: 1.111<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>(14 - 7)</sup> = 240
Smallest: 1.000<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>(1 - 7)</sup> = ‭0.015625‬.‬  ‬

4 exponents bits:
* Offset:  2<sup>4-1</sup> - 1 = 7.
* Max exponent:  2<sup>4</sup> - 2 = 14.  An exponent of 15 is for infinity and NaN.
* Min exponent:  1.  An exponent of 0 is for sub-normals.

Smallest sub-normal, aside from 0.0: 0.001<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>(1 - 7)</sup> = ‭0.001953125‬‬.‬  ‬

Review [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding).

Comment: Thank you. How would you represent positive infinity?

Comment: @Ibim_Laha What is _your_ best guess for positive infinity?  Break it down into 3 parts: what sign, expo, frac?  I am confident you will get at least 2 of those right.

Comment: Sign is 1 exp is 15? What would the frac be?

Comment: @Ibim_Laha 0. Anything else is a NaN